# Setting Up Python Script tool ESRI arcpy to download files from table

Tags: arcpy

It's been years since working with ArcPy and I'm having trouble setting up the parameters in my script tool.

What I'm trying to do:

I have a layer file (.lyr) that is a state wide index grid of available elevation model tiles.  The layer's attribute table has a field "URL" that contains the download link.  In my map document, I want to be able to make a selection of records in the layer and download the elevation model image tiles in my selected project area.

[Here's the layer file. And the data table at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aczxP.png)

What works:

I can run the script tool successfully but it's downloading all 15,000 files in the table not just my selected records.

this is the .py behind my script tool:

`

```
import urllib

import os

import arcpy

#where am I saving the download?
path = (str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)))
os.chdir(path)


#path to my index layer...stil unsure how to get this as a dropdown menu item in my tool
fc= r"C:\Users\Z\Desktop\LiDAR_Index.lyr"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

for row in cursor:
    field ="URL"
    link =(row.getValue(field))
    head, tail = os.path.split(str(link))
    print "Downloading: "+ tail
    download=urllib.urlretrieve((str(link)), tail)
```

`

I'm lost as to how to only make this act on the selected records and not the whole feature class or shapefile.

[Current UI on left and tool properties on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfa3K.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a map layer in your map document, you need to work not on the .lyr file, but instead on the [`Layer` object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm). To get the Layer object in your current map document, use the [`arcpy.ListLayers()` function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm).

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
map_lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Lidar Index", df)[0].name
```

When you select certain features on the map, you run the cursor for the map layer object:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(map_lyr,"url_field_name") as cur:
  for row in cur:
    #code
```

The cursors respect the selection; so you get back only the rows that were selected.